# Open popup when hover in specific word

Tags: jquery, popup

Good morning.

I have several pages with content that correspond to some products details.

What i need is for some words in that description, to open a popup with a description of that word.

An example:

> Microsoft Windows 7 Pro 64 PT OEM

When the mouse is hover "OEM" a popup appears with the description about what is OEM.

I would do it with a specific list of words that have that behavior.

It's something like mashable.com for example, at the side of the Windows word you have an icon, and if you hover it, opens a popup.

What is the best way to do that?

Using jquery to find the word and associate to it the popup?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching for tooltips and not pop-ups.

If you only want to display some text then you can set a link with a title attribute. And then display a tooltip based on the title-attribute. (As done with the jQuery plugin [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/features/#degradable).)

Another interesting jQuery plugin for you could be [jTip](http://codylindley.com/blogstuff/js/jtip/).

Comment: Yes, it's tooltip, not pop-up. :)
Thank you, it will solve my problem.